# IOS UIWebView not working?

Tags: ios, webview

I am using this code to load a url in `UIWebView`. A white screen appears only

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad]; 

     NSString *link = @"http://www.apple.com/";

     NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:link];

     NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

     [webView loadRequest:req];

 }
```

Comment: Do you initialize the webview and add as subview?

Comment: how you have declared your webView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems right, check that the webview is properly init:

```
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:myframe]
[self.view addSubview:ewebView];
```

Or the IBOutlet is correctly assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are initializing webView. If you are using IBOutlet then it gets allocated when your view is loaded. If you are not using IBOutlet then alloc init it using :

```
UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
```

Also try adding it as subview :

```
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 0):

First Be clear that Your WebView iS added to `self.view`.

And Follow following step.

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.apple.com/"];
//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```