# UIWebView does not load full content from an url

Tags: ios

I have a UIWebView where i load a url. But it does not load full content. I have checked all possible forums for solution but couldn't find a breakthrough yet. Any help would be really appreciated? You can try out the below url yourself. Basically, the url is supposed to contain html5 content/player.

```
-(void)loadPlayerUrl
{
    activityIndicatorView.hidden = NO;
    NSURL* nsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://watch.nimbletv.com/tv"]
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
    [self.playerWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

However, this works perfectly in safari or any other browser.

Comment: Which part of contents cannot be displayed ?

Comment: it just displays the title. It's supposed to load a html5 player after that but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `ViewControllerWebPage`
Then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.screenName = @"Info Ekran";
    NSURL *mobileCreaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobilecrea.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:mobileCreaURL];
    [mobileCrea loadRequest:myRequest];

}
```

Also create new view, select your new custom class (ViewControllerWebPage) and than create UIWebView

Comment: it won't solve the issue. OP already has the `self.playerWebView`, assuming it's a `UIWebView`. What is `self.screenName` used for?

Comment: Create new screen on storyboard then create new class but subclass of ViewControllerWebPage write codes here and connect your class on storyboard

Comment: OP can load part of the website. Did you read the question carefully?

Comment: Yes, when you implement this code like this still does not load full content.

Comment: Check this one , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167857/ios-uiwebview-not-working